# ¿Tener dos sesiones abiertas?

Tags: php, html

Quiero tener dos sesiones abiertas.

Una para guardar datos del usuario y otra para guardar datos del carro de compras.

Se puede o no, trate de renombrar la sesión pero sigue sin funcionar.

EDIT:
En esta parte de aquí trato de guardar el id de un producto en la sesión "carro"

```
$_SESSION['carro'][$id]
```

Y aquí guardo el id y el nombre del usuario que se ha logueado

```
$_SESSION['user']['id'] = $iD;
$_SESSION['user']['name'] = $usern;
```

Trato de guardar variables en diferentes sesiones.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta y agregar el código `PHP` en donde utilizas las variables de sesión? No me quedo del todo claro la parte de: *trate de renombrar la sesión* ¿Qué quieres decir? Te sugiero que leas [ask] y [mcve] para entender cómo funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

> `$_SESSION` es una variable superglobal que almacena un array asociativo con todas las variables de sesión. Si necesitas guardar más de un valor solamente hay que especificar la clave (puede ser una cadena o un número) y su contenido.

[Documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/book.session.php)

---

El problema es que estás creando la clave de forma dinámica y va a depender del valor que obtengas desde la base de datos. Además, la clave `['carro'][$id]` solo esta inicializada pero no tiene ningún valor.

```
$_SESSION['carro'][$id];
```

La solución pasa por escribir la clave de la variable de sesión entre comillas y asignarle el valor de la variable `$id`.

```
$_SESSION['carro']['id'] = $id;
```

Si queres obtener al valor de la variable de sesión `['carro]['id']`:

```
echo $_SESSION['carro']['id'];
// 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Claro, simplemente utiliza nombres de sesiones distintas.

Por ejemplo:

```
$_SESSION['USUARIO']['user']...
```